# SQL - Diferença entre MandatoryKey e MandatoryFKey

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou no meu primeiro estagio desde que comecei TI e a área na qual estou estagiando é a de DataBases. Tenho estudados uns scripts antigos e vi que algumas variaveis foram declaradas, como por exemplo: @country AS **MandatoryFKey**.
Até então eu já tinha conhecimento do que era uma *MandatoryKey*, porem nunca tinha lido sobre **MandatoryFKey**.

Fiz a minha pesquisa antes e não encontrei referencias satisfatórias no google e nem no stackoverflow portugues ou inglês. Alguém saberia me explicar se existe alguma diferença entre MandatoryKey e MandatoryFKey?
Obrigada

Comment: Nunca vi tal denominação mas deduzo que MandatoryFKey deva significar Mandatory Foreign Key que quer dizer que a chave estrangeira deva obrigatoriamente estar preenchida, isto é, que o relacionamento é obrigatório.

Comment: @anonimo, tive o mesmo feeling a respeito, mas procurei alguma informaçao mais concreta sobre isso e nao encontrei. Obrigada.